# Data source config with spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, datasource

Im looking for create jpa datasource for my application with configuration java, and i wrote the code below:

```
@ComponentScan("com.package.datasource.*")
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean(name = "datasource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource
                = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:3309/example?autoReconnect=true");
        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("pwddb");
        return  dataSource;
    }
}
```

and in datasource.xml i have:

```
<bean id="datasource" class="com.package.datasource.DataSourceConfig"/>
    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
            <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath*:META-INF/persist.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="datasource" />
            <property name="dataSources">
                <map>
                    <entry key="datasource" value-ref="datasource" />
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

i have this exception when Im looking for start application:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceUnitManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config/datasource.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type [com.package.datasource.DataSourceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4033708d] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'defaultDataSource'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.oxylane.cadplm.shapes.datasource.DataSourceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4033708d] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'defaultDataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Comment: What `DataSource` import are you using?

Comment: I use this :import javax.sql.DataSource;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line and it should be good.

```
<bean id="datasource" class="com.package.datasource.DataSourceConfig"/>
```

Your above line is wrong as the class of the datasource in order to instantiate datasource is not DataSourceConfig.

DataSourceConfig is a configuration class which will create an instance of datasource from `javax.sql.dataSource` The datasource will be automatically available for your application from the annotation

```
@Bean(name = "datasource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
    ...
```

So the first line that I indicated here is not needed for your application and is actualy wrong as it would probably needed to be

```
<bean id="datasource" class="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

But as already said you don't need it as you define it by annotations in your DataSourceConfig.

Comment: thank you for your response. I have explore this and i have this exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceUnitManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config/datasource.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'datasource' while setting bean property 'defaultDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'datasource' is defined 'Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'datasource' is defined'

Comment: your class DataSourceConfig is not picked up by spring. Move it to the same package where the class with `@SpringBootApplication` exists

Comment: I don't have spring boot application, but when i changed the position of package datasource where spring scan class it work, thank you for your help.